# Safe method return type for unknown generic during construction

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have a class as follows

```
public class GenericObjectBuilder {

    private Class<?> classType;

    public GenericObjectBuilder(Class<?> classType) {
       this.classType = classType;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add a method (eg getObject) to this class that will return an object of type '?', so that the constructor will determine the return type of this method. Eg

```
GenericObjectBuilder gc1 = new GenericObjectBuilder(String.class);
String value = gc1.getObject();

GenericObjectBuilder gc2 = new GenericObjectBuilder(Integer.class);
Integer value = gc2.getObject();
```

I cannot use proper generics in this scenario. For example I cannot do

```
GenericObjectBuilder<String> gc1 = new GenericObjectBuilder<>();
String value = gc1.getValue();
```

Is this possible using the constructor argument?

Comment: Don't use a wildcard. Make your class generic, use a type parameter.

Comment: Indeed, why can't you just make your entire class generic? (`public class GenericObjectBuilder<T> { ... }`)

Comment: I explained in the question, in this scenario I cannot use generics, I am at the mercy of a third party api and dont have the capability to do this.

Comment: @JonathanViccary: Oh, then I'm afraid you're stuck :(  You're asking for compile-time stuff to be affected by run-time knowledge.

Comment: I'm afraid, that's not possible without making the class generic!!

Comment: @JonathanViccary Perhaps if you gave us more info about what you are trying to accomplish, we could help you more.

Comment: I thought so. Phrasing it like that has illuminated the problem for me. At the moment, I'm just resorting to doing getObject(String.class) and putting a generic on the method.

Comment: Well, is it possible to make the class generic, and create a new instance with the knowledge of the class type at runtime? Ie i have 
Class<?> someClass = thirdPartyObject.getPropertyClass();
GenericObjectBuilder<?> gc = new GenericObjectBuilder<>(); ?

Comment: @JonathanViccary Sadly, no!! Generics are only available till compilation. At runtime, there is no generic type information left.

Answer (score 1):

Without Generics I am not sure you will be able to achieve what you target.

Depending on how tied you are to this 3rd party library, you could try and design around it.

- Pass in a wrapper object.

  If you have control over the constructor and implementation of the `GenericObjectBuilder` you could pass in a wrapper object.

  ```
  GenericObjectResult<String> result = new GenericObjectResult<>(String.class);
  GenericObjectBuilder builder = new GenericObjectBuilder(result);
  builder.build();
  String object = result.getObject();
  ```

  This is quite ugly but might as well get you going.
- Have only the `getObject` method generic.

  You should be able to have the following implementation.

  ```
  GenericObjectBuilder builder = new GenericObjectBuilder();
  String value = builder.getObject(String.class)
  ```

  This last implementation is a bit cleaner but you still need to use generics for the `getObject` method. The class itself will not be generic, though. Maybe this will be OK with the 3rd party library.
- Make a wrapper builder

  This last approach creates a wrapper builder on top of the `GenericObjectBuilder`.

  ```
  GenericObjectBuilder builder = new GenericObjectBuilder(String.class); // We don't actually care what the constructor is
  GenericObjectBuilderWrapper wrapper = new GenericObjectBuilderWrapper(builder, String.class); // You could try and get the class from the `builder` if it has the proper API
  String value = wrapper.getObject();
  ```

  What the wrapper would do internally, would be something of this kind.

  ```
  class GenericObjectBuilderWrapper<T> {
      private Class<T> clazz;
      private GenericObjectBuilder delegate;

      public GenericObjectBuilderWrapper(GenericObjectBuilder delegate, Class<T> clazz) {
          this.clazz = clazz;
          this.delegate = delegate;
      }

      public <T> getObject() {
          final Object value = delegate.getObject();
          return clazz.cast(value);
      }

  }
  ```

If you really cannot use any type of generic anywhere in the project because you are using older version of Java, then you will have to rely on explicit casting.

```
String value = (String)builder.getObject();
```